# Read and write file on server in java

Tags: java, server

I, have web-app, want store files in server. which method I should follow to read and write files in server.

I done mapped network drive to my remote location and tried to read and write files but it's not worked well due to some security issue. 
In my project all clients have a common server/Cloud to store there files, so each time I need to validate clients before giving file accessing permission.

Which method I should follow to achieve this? 
All good leads will be appreciatable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "some security error" probably means that you are not allowed to read or write.  If you are not allowed, you are not allowed.   Talk to the people who manage the remote file server and ask them to grant you permission to do what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have full permission to read and write. I written files there and I tried to download it(pdf). but it's not working.. The  url is like this "file://xx2.xx8.1.x2/user1/test/Reports/Report20191365.pdf ".  I don't know how to download file from shared location. may be that is issue.